# Odoo: Override Integer field in onchange not working whereas Float is changed - WHY?

Tags: odoo

I have extended the product.template with following fields:

```
length = fields.Integer("Length", default=0)
length_float = fields.Float("Float", default=0.0)
```

Additionally I have extended the product.packaging model with this fields and an onchange method:

```
product_id_ref = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Reference")
length = fields.Integer('Length')
length_float = fields.Float('Length_Float')

@api.onchange("product_id_ref")
def _onchange_product(self):        
    if self.product_id_ref:
        self.length_float = self.product_id_ref.length_float
        self.length = self.product_id_ref.length
```

Interestingly the **FLOAT** field length_float **is changed** as expected and shown in the view. The **INTEGER** field **is not changed**.

Something more suprising is that if I change the order of the onchange method

```
@api.onchange("product_id_ref")
def _onchange_product(self):        
    if self.product_id_ref:
        self.length = self.product_id_ref.length
        self.length_float = self.product_id_ref.length_float
```

**NO value is changed**!

How could that be?? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have one onchange event, it may be another onchange event that cancel the modification

Comment: would you please make sure that `product_id_ref` holds a value on both `length`, `length_float`

Answer (score 0):

It came out that the problem was the 'length' field itself. This name leads to problems on the javascript side. Renaming leads to the desired result.